# How can I write this javascript logic code into a more efficient/compact way?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In a project I am working on I have 21 buttons that all have active and inactive states. The state of certain buttons is affected by other buttons being pressed as well as that button being pressed. In my html I use ng-click to call a function updateActiveButtons(num) to activate or deactivate certain buttons.

The best way I could think of was to use an array of 21 elements, all of which were set to false by default and then changed when they were pressed.

The problem is that my code is UGLY and I know that there has to be a much better way to logic it out.

Here is my updateActiveButtons function:

```
/* Array for active buttons
0: Company Name 1: Country 2: Industry 3: Search 4: Company Name - Seller Name 5: Company Name - Buyer Name 6: Country - USA 7: Country - China 8: Country - Israel 
9: Country - Russia 10: Country - India 11: Country - Japan 12: Industry - Tech 13: Industry - Consumer 14: Industry - Pharma 15: Industry - Financial 16: Industry - Biotech 17: Industry - Industrial 
18: Date 19: Valuation 20: Industry - Business
*/
$scope.activeButtonArray = new Array(21);
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.activeButtonArray.length; i++) { $scope.activeButtonArray[i] = false; }
//pos = position in array
$scope.updateActiveButtons = function(pos) {
    console.log($scope.activeButtonArray[20]);
    if(pos != 0 || pos != 1 || pos != 2 || pos != 3 || pos != 4 || pos != 5) {
        $scope.activeButtonArray[pos] = !$scope.activeButtonArray[pos];
    } else if(pos == 3 && !$scope.activeButtonArray[pos]) {
        $scope.activeButtonArray[pos] = true;
    } else if(pos == 3 && $scope.activeButtonArray[pos]) {
        $scope.activeButtonArray[pos] = false;
    }
    if(pos == 18 || pos == 19) {
        $scope.activeButtonArray[0] = false;
        if($scope.activeButtonArray[6] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[7] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[8] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[9] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[10] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[11] == false) {
            $scope.activeButtonArray[1] = false;
        }
        if($scope.activeButtonArray[12] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[13] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[14] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[15] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[16] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[17] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[20] == false) {
            $scope.activeButtonArray[2] = false;
        }
    }
    if(pos == 0) {
        $scope.activeButtonArray[0] = true;
        if($scope.activeButtonArray[4] || $scope.activeButtonArray[5]) {
            $scope.activeButtonArray[0] = true;
        }
        if($scope.activeButtonArray[6] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[7] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[8] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[9] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[10] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[11] == false) {
            $scope.activeButtonArray[1] = false;
        }
        if($scope.activeButtonArray[12] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[13] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[14] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[15] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[16] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[17] == false  && $scope.activeButtonArray[20] == false) {
            $scope.activeButtonArray[2] = false;
        }
        if($scope.search.text == undefined || $scope.search.text == '') {
            $scope.activeButtonArray[3] = false;
        }
    }
    if(pos == 1) {
        if($scope.activeButtonArray[4] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[5] == false) {
            $scope.activeButtonArray[0] = false;
        }
        if($scope.activeButtonArray[6] == true || $scope.activeButtonArray[7] == true || $scope.activeButtonArray[8] == true || $scope.activeButtonArray[9] == true || $scope.activeButtonArray[10] == true || $scope.activeButtonArray[11] == true) {
            $scope.activeButtonArray[1] = true;
        }
        if($scope.activeButtonArray[12] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[13] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[14] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[15] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[16] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[17] == false  && $scope.activeButtonArray[20] == false) {
            $scope.activeButtonArray[2] = false;
        }
        if($scope.search.text == undefined || $scope.search.text == '') {
            $scope.activeButtonArray[3] = false;
        }
    }
    if(pos == 2) {
        if($scope.activeButtonArray[4] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[5] == false) {
            $scope.activeButtonArray[0] = false;
        }
        if($scope.activeButtonArray[6] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[7] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[8] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[9] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[10] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[11] == false) {
            $scope.activeButtonArray[1] = false;
        }
        if($scope.activeButtonArray[12] == true || $scope.activeButtonArray[13] == true || $scope.activeButtonArray[14] == true || $scope.activeButtonArray[15] == true || $scope.activeButtonArray[16] == true || $scope.activeButtonArray[17] == true  || $scope.activeButtonArray[20] == true) {
            $scope.activeButtonArray[2] = true;
        }
        if($scope.search.text == undefined || $scope.search.text == '') {
            $scope.activeButtonArray[3] = false;
        }
    }
    if(pos == 3) {
        if($scope.activeButtonArray[4] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[5] == false) {
            $scope.activeButtonArray[0] = false;
        }
        if($scope.activeButtonArray[6] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[7] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[8] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[9] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[10] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[11] == false) {
            $scope.activeButtonArray[1] = false;
        }
        if($scope.activeButtonArray[12] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[13] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[14] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[15] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[16] == false && $scope.activeButtonArray[17] == false  && $scope.activeButtonArray[20] == false) {
            $scope.activeButtonArray[2] = false;
        }
    }
    if(pos == 4) {
        $scope.activeButtonArray[4] = true;
        $scope.activeButtonArray[5] = false;
    }
    if(pos == 5) {
        $scope.activeButtonArray[4] = false;
        $scope.activeButtonArray[5] = true;
    }
}
```

I have a lot of repeated code that comes out in a way that just doesn't feel very well done or professional. I wouldn't be proud to send this to a client. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I could make this better?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On way would be to replace entire conditions (or blocks) by methods/functions

so

```
    if($scope.activeButtonArray[4] || $scope.activeButtonArray[5]) {
        $scope.activeButtonArray[0] = true;
    }
```

becomes

```
if (somethingIsSomething($scope))
```

This has the added benefit of be much more self-documenting so you can "read" what you're doing.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I like the idea of a function that will take the array, and a start and end point in the array. Will return true if one or more is true, will return false if all are false.

Comment: yeah, if you are always wanting either to check a range for all true or all false.

Comment: I actually wanted to check if any single one was true, but the concept was the same and you led me to my answer, thank you. I'm going to post what I did as an answer, but I'll mark yours as correct since you led me to it.

Answer (score 0):

I liked pixelearth's recommendation to just create another function so I did.

I decided to make a function that took an array, a start, and a end point as parameters and return true if any of the array values in that range are true.

Here is the function:

```
var arrayContainsTrue = function(arr, start, end) {
    for(var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        if(arr[i] == true) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and then to shorten my code I just did this (with different start and end points based on what was needed):

```
if(!arrayContainsTrue($scope.activeButtonArray, 6, 11))
```